# Calling a closure from a popup window?

Tags: javascript, popup, closures, call

I have an aspx page that has a reference to index.js inside the js I have a closures like thes one below, then from the page I open a popup window which has a reference to page1.js , Is there any way to call the closure and assign it to a variable in page.js, so I can use the closure methods and update the _var1.

Im opening the popup window within the same domain as the parent index.aspx page. I already tried using code in page.js like: var _closure = window.opener.UI_Methods(); but I got the following error: Unable to evaluate the expression. Call was rejected by callee. in the Immediate Window on VS 2010 when debugging.

Is there a way I can call a closure in the parent page and update variables by calling the closure methods?

```
UI_Methods = function(){

 var _var1 = var1 || null;

 var _setVar1 = function(var1){
    _var1 = var1;
 };

 var _getVar1 = function(){
    return _var1;
 };

 return {
   SetVar1 : _serVar1

 };
```

};